# How to enable the counter of Timers in ARM CORTEX M3(STM32F103RB)?

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m, keil

I am trying to write code for toggling a pin(Pin 15) of a port (PORTC) using timers(specifically TIM2). I have to use the prescale registers to divide the clock frequency such that I obtain the required delay for toggling the pin.
So I wrote some code after 3 hrs of going through Reference Manual of the STM32F103RB. I checked what is wrong with my program and noticed that the Counter register is not updating even though I enabled the counter enable pin.
Could anyone tell where I am going wrong? I have attached my code for reference.

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

void Q2() {
    int step = 0;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<4);  //To enable the PORTC
    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1<<0);  // Enable Timer 2
    GPIOC->CRH &= (0<<30);   // setting CNF
    GPIOC->CRH |= (1<<28);   // Setting mode to get general purpose Output push pull
    
    TIM2->PSC = 0xD2F0;    // Prescalar value set such that the 0.5ms is over till overflow
    TIM2->CR1 |= 1<<7;  // Auto reload preload enable is buffered
    TIM2->ARR = 0x0000;  // Auto reload value is 0
    TIM2->CR1 |= 1<<0;  //Counter enabled

    while (1)
    {
        TIM2->PSC = 0xD2F0;    // Prescalar value set such that the 0.5ms is over till overflow 
        TIM2->CR1 |= 1<<7;  // Auto reload preload enable is buffered
        TIM2->ARR = 0x0000;  // Auto reload value is 0
        TIM2->CR1 |= 1<<0;  //Counter enabled
        TIM2->SR &= 0<<0;
        while(step!=2) {
            if((TIM2->SR && 0x0001) == 0x0001) {

                step++; 
            }
        }
        step = 0;
        GPIOC->BSRR |= (1<<15);  // set pin 15 of port C
        TIM2->PSC = 0xD2F0;    // Prescalar value set such that the 0.5ms is over till overflow 
        TIM2->CR1 |= 1<<7;  // Auto reload preload enable is buffered
        TIM2->ARR = 0x0000;  // Auto reload value is 0
        TIM2->CR1 |= 1<<0;  //Counter enabled   
        TIM2->SR &= 0<<0;
        while(step!=2) {
            if((TIM2->SR && 0x0001) == 0x0001) {

                step++; 
            }
        }
        step = 0;
        
        GPIOC->BSRR |= (1<<31);  // reset pin 15 of Port C
    }
        
    }
    int main ()
    {
        SystemInit ();
        Q2();
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: There are named constants for all those number in the part header file.  Replace all the magic numbers with the correct constant and you will have some code that is reviewable and maintainable.  Then you will be able to see what is wrong :-).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not set the `TIM2_ARR` register to zero. This register determines the maximum value of the counter before generating update or interrupt event by the timer. So if you set it to zero the counter won't start counting. You should configure the value of `TIM2_PSC` and `TIM2_ARR` registers  based on `SytemCoreClock` Variable (the clock frequency of your MCU) to get the desired delay for toggling the GPIO pin.

And also you don't need to re-configure the timer every time after toggling the GPIO pin. If you want to reset the timer and start counting from zero `TIM2->CNT &= 0x0` would be enough.